# how to pass params using action button in grails

Tags: grails, button, submit, action, parameters

been having toruble with the button that has action. I have several btns which I want to know its paramaeter. In grails tutorial it says it should be like this:

```
 <g:actionSubmit    action="action" value="${message(code: 'default.button.edit.label', default: 'Edit')}" params="['actionTaken':editPhone]"/>
```

I tried using remotelink, submitButton, submitToRemote  tags but none works. I always get null when I try parsing it in my controller:

```
def action=
    {
        def actionTaken = params.actionTaken
        def employeeId= params.employeeId

        MySession session = MySession.getMySession(request, params.employeeId)
        profileInstance = session.profileInstance

        switch(actionTaken)
        {
            case "editPhone" :
                isEditPhone=true
                break

            case "editEmail" :
                isEditEmail=true
                break
        }
        render(view:"profile", model:[profileInstance:session.profileInstance, isEditPhone:isEditPhone, isEditEmail:isEditEmail])
    }
```

What am I missing? is my params code wrong? Is my code in parsing params wrong? this just gets me in circles with no progress. help. thanks.

Comment: Have you tried **<g:actionSubmit    action="action" value="${message(code: 'default.button.edit.label', default: 'Edit', params:['actionTaken':editPhone])}"/>**. Maybe I forgot {} on the params attribute, if it doesn't works try to put them like **[{}]** or **{[]}** I don't remenber right now how it was. Sry

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Grails documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/actionSubmit.html) doesn't list `params` as one of the attributes accepted by `actionSubmit`.

It *is* possible to inject the value you want in your params list in the controller by exploiting what that tag *actually* does:

```
def editPhone = { forward(action:'action', params:[actionTaken: 'editPhone'])}
def editEmail = { forward(action:'action', params:[actionTaken: 'editEmail'])}
```

You may also just want to just code completely separate logic into the `editPhone` and `editEmail` actions if that makes your code cleaner.

Updated View Code:

```
<g:actionSubmit action="editPhone" value="${message(code: 'default.button.edit.label', default: 'Edit')}" />
```

Answer (score 4):

The `params` attribute is parsed as a map, where the *keys* are treated a strings but the *values* are treated as expressions.  Therefore

```
params="['actionTaken':editPhone]"
```

is trying to define the key named `actionTaken` to have the value from the variable named `editPhone` in the GSP model.  Since there is no such variable you're getting null.  So the fix is to move the quotes:

```
params="[actionTaken:'editPhone']"
```

which will set the value to the string "editPhone".

Comment: Actually, I did that already before I posted in here and still null. :(

Answer (score 3):

You could also pass the parameter inside the POST-data using

```
<input type="hidden" name="actionTaken" value="editPhone" />
```

inside the form. Then it is also accessible through the params variable. 
It works for me.

Comment: This is the correct answer imho.  You have to remember that the context of the <g:actionSubmit> is within a form, and that the form will be submitted to the action listed in the <g:actionSubmit> tag.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem (I needed to submit a delete together with an id) and found a solution using HTML5's "formaction" attribute for submit-inputs.
They can be given a value that can include a controller, action, additional parameters, etc.

In General, to add a parameter to a submit button such as a edit of a specific sub-object on a form would looks like this:

```
<input type="submit" formaction="/<controller>/<action>/<id>?additionalParam1=...&additionalParam2=..." value="Action" >
```

and in your example:

```
<input type="submit" formaction="action?actionTaken=editPhone" value="${message(code: 'default.button.edit.label', default: 'Edit')}" >
```

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, I had a single form element with multiple actions on each row of a table (i.e. data table edit buttons). It was important to send the entire form data so I couldn't just use links. The quickest way I found to inject a parameter was with javascript. Not ideal, but it works:

```
function injectHiddenField(name, value) {
    var control = $("input[type=hidden][name='" + name + "']");
    if (control.size() == 0) {
        console.log(name + " not found; adding...");
        control = $("<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"" + name + "\" name=\"" + name + "\">");
        $("form").append(control);
    }
    control.val(value);
}
```

Your button can look like this:

```
<g:each in="${objects}" var="object">
     ...
     <g:actionSubmit value="edit" action="anotherAction"
                     onclick="injectHiddenField('myfield', ${object.id})"/>
</g:each>
```